# C-Programming.Why Doesn't This Work?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

The following program should search over a multi-dimensional array. When I enter the word `town` as input, it should return `Track 1: Newark,Newark-A Wonderful Town` but I don't receive any output (nothing happens), any ideas how to fix it?

I'm working on the **Head First C** book.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* Run this program using the console pauser
or add your own _getch, system("pause") or input loop */

char tracks[][80]={
        "I Left My Heart In Harvard Med School",
        "Newark,Newark-A Wonderful Town",
        "From Here to Maternity",
        "The Girl From Iwo Jima",
    };


void find_track(char search_for[]){
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<=4;i++){
        if(strstr(tracks[i],search_for)){

            printf("Track %i:'%s' \n",i,tracks[i]);

    }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char search_for[80];
    printf("Search for: ");
    fgets(search_for,80,stdin);
    find_track(search_for);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Town` != `town`.

Comment: Both don't work

Comment: @光量子 Apart from what is pointed out in the first comment, check the manual for `fgets` It reads the newline character too which is not what you would want.

Comment: `fgets` will read and store the newline, which won't match any line. You need to remove it.

Comment: Maybe you want this `strcasestr`?

Comment: If you give input as Town it will work. Because Town != town

Comment: Use a debugger. When you get to the point where you expect the strstr to find something, look very closely at the parameters.

Comment: There are no *newlines* (`'\n'`) in  `tracks`...

Comment: One point subtracted for useless title.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out above, `fgets` stores the newline from  your input, and it will not match. Chopping the last character off that `search_for` string will make it work, as long as you match the case of the test in the title.  Also, note that your `for` loop should have `i < 4` instead of `i <= 4`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */
char tracks[][80]={
        "I Left My Heart In Harvard Med School",
        "Newark,Newark-A Wonderful Town",
        "From Here to Maternity",
        "The Girl From Iwo Jima",
    };


void find_track(char search_for[]){
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<4;i++){
        if(strstr(tracks[i], search_for)){
          printf("Track %i:'%s' \n",i,tracks[i]);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char search_for[80];
    printf("Search for: ");
    fgets(search_for,80,stdin);
    search_for[strlen(search_for)-1] = '\0'; // truncate input
    find_track(search_for);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If the limit of 80 characters was reached before `\n` was encountered, the string will not contain `\n` at the end. Which is why unconditional truncation of the last character is not a very good practice. `search_for[strcspn(search_for, "\n")] = '\0';` might be a better idea.

Comment: You may try, `size_t len = strlen (search_for); if (len && search_for[len - 1] == '\n') search_for[--len] = 0;` (but other than than, you got the heart of the problem addressed) And you should validate `if (!fgets(...)) { /* handle user canceled input */ }`

Comment: Thank you for the additional input - all helpful!